# Node js - converting pdf to valid version

Tags: node.js, pdf

I have various pdf files which fail a certain logic process due to them being invalid.
I use - https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx

and when I validate a pdf, I get a message that says the pdf does not conform to the PDF 1.3 standard or 1.4 standard.

I'm familiar with converting the pdf to `text/json/buffer` and then rebuild it and save it as a new pdf file, but was wondering is there an alternative? Because each pdf is different and is basically user input and the rebuilding it using `jspdf` for example, will be different for every file.

Is it possible to convert such pdf document to conform to the PDF 1.3/1.4 standards?